# CSS: Align an element based on screen size

Tags: css, jsp, alignment

So I'm writing a program that will need to resize elements based on the viewers screen size. The program is in jsp / sql/ xhtml / css and I have a few questions.

Is there any way to select a css file by saving the screen width to a jsp variable?

Is there a way to align a div below another div and use the above div as a sort of container for it?   This question is a little complicated

Goal: To have an image with a text label underneath it.  Problem: The div is part of a parent div, and the div serves an image that will changed based on the screen size.

Here's something like what I'm doing.

```
<div id="container">
<div id="inner">
    <div class="1">--stuff</div>
    <div class="2"><img src="server:8080/project?minutes=720&width=<%= out.print(width) %> </div> <-- want to align under this
    <div class="3">--stuff</div>
</div>
<div id="label"> <--Want this div aligned underneath "2"
    <div class="1">2.0</div> <-- Want the text at 25% of the image (right)
    <div class="2">4.0</div> <-- Want the text at 50% of the image (right)
    <div class="3">6.0</div> <-- Want the text at 75% of the image (right)
    <div class="4">8.0</div> <-- Want the text at 100% of the image (right)
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Media queries come to mind: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width

Comment: As @TheZ said, media queries. You can also research "Responsive Design" as well

Comment: I like the idea of a media query, I don't get how that helps me progress with my issues here though, as I don't see anything about extracting the screen width as a variable in that.

Comment: @Damien.Bell With the query method you don't need to. You can have the layout change based on the width if you need drastic layout reorganizing. For other adjustments I'd just use CSS percents that already adjust based on available space.

Comment: Well, it would be pretty drastic, but if you see the second part of my question it sort of explains that.   Unfortunately the company that I'm making this for uses panel monitors (900x1600)x2 and 2560x1600 main monitors, so I have to make my layout viable across a span of 1660px  So the width is a huge pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are wanting to do - Responsive Design - is very cool but also gets pretty complicated. It takes a bit of learning, but CodeSchool has a high quality course called [Journey Into Mobile](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/journey-into-mobile) that covers adaptive screen sizes and should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dig into Responsive design, Media Queries & Fluid layouts. 
As mentioned above Codeschool does have a great course covering these areas.